I got build error in flutter when i tried to run my flutter app on my phone
I am making a flutter project about metro routes. The app has the user insert their start station and their ending station, and the app shows an output of the time that the trip will take, the ticket price, and if they should change lanes during the trip.
So today I was trying to add location feature in the app so that the app find the nearest station for the user using geolocator package. After I added the location permission in the app, it stopped running on my phone, restarting it ended giving me the error below. However, it still runs without any problem on the web.

This is the error message:
B Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: ProcessException: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.

  Command: D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dartaotruntime.exe
--disable-dart-dev D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\snapshots\frontend_server_aot.dart.snapshot
--sdk-root D:\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\common\flutter_patched_sdk/
--target=flutter --no-print-incremental-dependencies -Dflutter.inspector.structuredErrors=true -Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts --track-widget-creation --no-link-platform --packages "D:\flutter projects\metroo\.dart_tool\package_config.json" --output-dill "D:\flutter projects\metroo\.dart_tool\flutter_build\f1178b7182ea457ada49e621d8d7c094\program.dill"
--depfile "D:\flutter projects\metroo\.dart_tool\flutter_build\f1178b7182ea457ada49e621d8d7c094\kernel_snapshot_program.d"
--incremental --initialize-from-dill "D:\flutter projects\metroo\.dart_tool\flutter_build\f1178b7182ea457ada49e621d8d7c094\program.dill"
--source file:///D:/flutter%20projects/metroo/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart
--source package:flutter/src/dart_plugin_registrant.dart -Dflutter.dart_plugin_registrant=file:///D:/flutter%20projects/metroo/.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart
--verbosity=error package:metroo/main.dart


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'D:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 53s Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to take the code of the old project without putting the location permissions and it worked, but when I tried to put the permissions in the android manifest file it ended giving me the same error in the new project. (I am using Android Studio)
